# Length of values in column

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to know if the values in column C (unknown rows) contain 6 digits.
If not, add one or more 0 in column B to obtain 6 digits.

Here an image to better understand:
[image: Table example]

```vb
Dim nbchar As Integer
nbchar = Len(Columns("C"))

If IsNumeric(Columns("C") And (nbchar<6) Then
    Columns("B").Value = 0
```

Comment: You said "6 numbers" but do you mean "6 digits" instead?

Comment: Also, would a formula work for you instead of VBA code? If so, seems easy enough to do with a formula.

Comment: Hi @icodeplenty, yes I mean "6 digits" (I'm French, sorry ^^). Could you tell me the formula ?

Comment: Something like `=IF(LEN(C1) < 6, REPT("0",6 - LEN(C1)))` in cell B1 might work (untested). Copy the formula down to other rows if it works.

Comment: Hi @RaymondWu, your formula is working, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for VBA like icodeplenty said, excel formula is sufficient for this task:

`=IF(LEN(C1) < 6, REPT("0",6 - LEN(C1)))` in cell B2 and fill down the rows.

Comment: Exactly what I was going to post if OP changed the question. As it stands, this is a VBA question though. Very nice formula RaymondWu.